# How do I set a user as inactive in Django when registering?

Tags: python, django

When registering, I'd like a moderator to manually set users as active instead of allowing them to be automatically set as active. Here's what I'm using in my **users/views.py**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            # login(request, user)
            # messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in!')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to=get_upload_path)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

Edit:

So, for other's reading this, this is what worked for me: In signals.py, I placed:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
def set_new_user_inactive(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance._state.adding is True:
        print("Creating Inactive User")
        instance.is_active = False
    else:
        print("Updating User Record")
```

Comment: Please provide us your models.py!!!

Comment: Added the models.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you want. But, I would recomment you to signals to acheive the goal. Also, signals are pretty important as you go far so better use that from now. Add this *signals* to `models.py`.

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def user_to_inactive(sender, instance, created, update_fields, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.is_active = False
```

Now, lets talk little bit about
[Django_signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/). They are like callback, after you do something, it will call the connected function. `reciever` decorator is to connect the signal and there is `pre_save` argument which specifies that call `user_to_inactive` fuction before the save method of user is called, `sender` is the model which is going to send the signals to the function. So, when instance is created, we will make `user instance`'s `is_active` to false.